# Работа с внешним python скриптом на django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Есть проект на django.

- 1-ый вопрос. Нужно встроить python скрипт в его работу. Т.е. по нажатии какой либо кнопки запускается этот скрипт. Как это реализовать? JS?
- 2-ой вопрос. Нужно сделать так, чтобы python скрипт запускался вместе с сервером. Т.е. есть парсер, нужно сделать так, чтобы он запускался вместе с сервером. Как это сделать?

Новенький во всем этом, начинаю осваиваться, помогите, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, это не самые правильные способы решения, но все равно напишу:

1. Можешь добавить в кнопку аттрибут `onclick`, который запускает javasckript функцию, который будет посылать `fetch` запрос в определенный маршрут, и в представлении для этого маршрута запускать парсер.
2. можешь добавить в начало `manage.py` код, который запускает парсер.
   Добавлено: есть ещё managment commands

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)